# Select latest test score for each student for each subject they have taken

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to do a pull of all the latest test scores in the table TestScores for each subject a student has been in. Example below.

```
STUDENT_ID   SUBJECT   SCORE   TEST_DATE 
1            math      90%     11/5/2018
1            math      88%     1/12/2019
1            science   74%     12/9/2018
2            math      79%     10/10/2018
2            science   68%     2/25/2019 
1            science   72%     6/14/2018
2            art       93%     9/22/2018
3            art       73%     10/20/2018



Desired output:

STUDENT_ID   SUBJECT   SCORE   TEST_DATE 
1            math      88%     1/12/2019
1            science   74%     12/9/2018
2            math      79%     10/10/2018    
2            science   68%     2/25/2019 
2            art       93%     9/22/2018
3            art       73%     10/20/2018
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leverage [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for this.

```
select STUDENT_ID
    , SUBJECT
    , SCORE
    , TEST_DATE
from
(
    select STUDENT_ID
        , SUBJECT
        , SCORE
        , TEST_DATE
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by STUDENT_ID, SUBJECT order by TEST_DATE DESC)
    from TestScores
) x
where x.RowNum = 1
```

Comment: Perfect. Just what I needed. Thanks Sean.

Answer (score 0):

With this:

```
select student_id, subject, max(test_date) maxdate
from tablename 
group by student_id, subject
```

you get all the latest dates for each student and subject, 
so you join it to the table and get the results you want:

```
select t.* 
from tablename t inner join (
  select student_id, subject, max(test_date) maxdate
  from tablename 
  group by student_id, subject
) g
on g.student_id = t.student_id and g.subject = t.subject and g.maxdate = t.test_date
```